# Stacked bar plot disconnected

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

Data comes from this website.
https://www.kaggle.com/kemical/kickstarter-projects

My stacked bar plot is disconnected. I have not idea what is going on. None of my data contains any null values. The values of the series are frequencies. Has anyone encountered this? I just want to make my bars connected.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, figsize=(15,5))
x = clean_df['main_category'].value_counts().index


print("Number of unique main categories:", clean_df['main_category'].nunique())


for year in [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]:    
    y = clean_df[clean_df['launched'].dt.year == year]['main_category'].value_counts()
    if year > 2010:
        bottom = clean_df[clean_df['launched'].dt.year <= year-1]['main_category'].value_counts()
    else:
        bottom = 0
        
    ax.set_xlabel("Main Catagories", fontsize=14)
    ax.set_ylabel("Frequency/Count", fontsize=14)
    ax.bar(x=x, height=y, width=0.9, bottom=bottom, label=str(year))
    ax.yaxis.grid(linestyle='-', linewidth=0.7)
    ax.set_xticklabels(x, rotation=45, ha='right')
    ax.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.tight_layout();
```

[image]

Comment: each label has the same year in the plot (2016)

Comment: Why not use pandas to do the stacked bar plot? Seems like it'd be much easier.

Comment: The problem probably is that `clean_df[...]['main_category'].value_counts()` changes the order of the categories in every call (the order seems to be from large to small value count, which differs by year). So, the labels don't correspond to the bars. You will also see that the bars overlap if you set alpha=0.4 or so. It would be much better to use pandas or seaborn to create the plot, as suggested by BigBen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `clean_df[...]['main_category'].value_counts()` gives the values ordered from large to small. This can be different from year to year.

Appending `[x]` to `y` solves the problem, so effectively sorting `y` with the desired index.

To calculate the bottom of the bars, it is easier to accumulate the heights at the end of loop. Initializing `bottom = 0` together with some pandas magic makes sure that `bottom += y` sums the desired values. Only in case a `year` doesn't have a value for some category, this would set `na` for that category. Therefore, using `fillna(0)` after `y` has been reordered by `x` prevents accumulating `na`.

A simplified example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 100
clean_df = pd.DataFrame({'main_category': np.random.choice(list('abcdef'), N),
                         'year': np.random.randint(2010, 2017, N)})
x = clean_df['main_category'].value_counts().index

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, figsize=(15, 5))
bottom = 0
for year in [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]:
    y = clean_df[clean_df['year'] == year]['main_category'].value_counts()[x].fillna(0)
    ax.set_xlabel("Main Catagories", fontsize=14)
    ax.set_ylabel("Frequency/Count", fontsize=14)
    ax.bar(x=x, height=y, width=0.9, bottom=bottom, label=str(year), alpha=0.8)
    ax.yaxis.grid(linestyle='-', linewidth=0.7)
    ax.set_xticklabels(x, rotation=45, ha='right')
    ax.legend(loc='upper right')
    bottom += y
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: To create this plot with pandas:

```py
df_plot = clean_df.groupby(['year', 'main_category']).size().reset_index().pivot(columns='year', index='main_category', values=0)
df_plot['total'] = df_plot.sum(axis=1)
df_plot.sort_values('total', ascending=False, inplace=True)
df_plot[df_plot.columns[:-1]].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=45)
```

Note that you might need to create a new column in `clean_df` containing only the year.